# What is the function of /home in Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, folders

I would like to mirror the directory structure that I have on my linux machine at work. There, my home directory resides in `/home/emiller` rather than `/Users/emiller` as it does on Snow Leopard.

I was intending to create `/home/emiller` and use it as a sshfs mount point for my files on the linux machine - thus permitting to me run all my scripts without having to change any paths.

However, when I try to `mkdir /home/emiller`, I get:

`mkdir: /home/emiller: Operation not supported`

Why is this? What is the function of `/home`? It appears empty of all files.

~emiller

Comment: To run your scripis use ~ as the home directory or $HOME don't hardcode /home/emiller

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's got an NFS automounter map mounted on it, so NFS home directories will be automatically available there.  Quoting `man auto_master`:

> The `auto_master` file contains a list of the directories that are to be
>   automounted.  Associated with each directory is the name of a map that
>   lists the locations of the filesystems to be automounted there.  The
>   default map looks like this:
>
> ```
> #
> # Automounter master map
> #
> +auto_master            # Use directory service
> /net                    -hosts          -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
> /home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
> /Network/Servers        -fstab
> /-                      -static
> ```

The default `auto_home` on SL expects to get the home directory-to-machine mapping from NIS or LDAP, but you can add entries manually.

You can remove the `auto_home` line from `/etc/auto_master` and `sudo killall automountd` (which should cause `launchd` to rerun it with the new map) or reboot.  Alternately, add your `sshfs` mount to `/etc/auto_home` (and again restart `automountd` or reboot).

Comment: If I could vote your post up I would... I don't yet have enough reputation on this stackexchange site!

Comment: Nevermind, now I can.