# How can I use the /home directory on Mac OS X : revisited

Tags: mac, time-machine, catalina, filesystem

I would like to mount `/Users` to `/home` on my macbook (Catalina Version 10.15.6).

I have three systems: an Ubuntu laptop, a rhel server and a macbook. I have some python scripts (written by others) that uses configuration files where full file paths need to be mentioned (no `~`). I don't like changing the home path in the scripts from `/Users/x` to `/home/x` multiple times.

[There's this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362703/how-can-i-use-the-home-directory-on-mac-os-x/25558272#25558272) about the same thing but three years have passed and I wonder if anything has changed. The person who wrote the accepted answer himself recommend doing something else and I can not do that. I am genuinely concerned about two things:

1. Automatic back up of this folder.
2. Will a system update wipe this folder out?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195441/how-to-remove-home-directory?rq=1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/what-is-the-function-of-home-in-snow-leopard, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88797/how-to-execute-mkdir-in-home-directory

Comment: scripts should not have /home/x as the home directory for user x. It is not a standard - For most of my 30 years of Unix most systems were elsewhere and could differ in the same organisation. There is a standard though use $HOME for the current user or ~x for user x , if not using Bourne shell.

Comment: There is no `script`, there are config files that are used by some python codes.

Comment: In any case, I don't have control over the codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'm convinced that any software requiring hard coded paths to home directories is broken and needs to be fixed, but I understand that this isn't possible sometimes. So in your situation I would just disable the auto mounter for `/home` (see [How to remove '/home' directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195441/how-to-remove-home-directory?rq=1)) and then symlink `/home` to `/Users`. This also solves the backup issue.

PS: Biggest risk probably is that a future update will rewrite `auto_master` but that you can easily fix again.

Comment: Seems you can not just create a symlink `sudo ln -s /Users/ /home` returns `ln: /home: Read-only file system`. I think you have to disable SIP https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x .

Comment: @rivu Uhh, with SIP and Catalina this may become a challenge anyway.